# Not able to open videos after uploading in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, video

I have a sharepoint list. I can upload videos into it and the uploading works fine. I uploaded a wmv file and it showed a windows media player icon by default for the file. However, when i click on the video to open it, the media player opens up but it is not able to play the file. It gives an error that the format is not supported or the codec is not right.....But when I download it and play it using the windows media player, it works fine!! Does anyone know What could be the problem ??

Comment: When you say clicking on the file, media player opens up - does media player opens up in browser or launched as a standalone application?

Comment: Are you talking about SharePoint 2007 or 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint media player web part (I'm going to assume we're talking about 2010) is Silverlight based, and does not share the same supported codecs as native Windows Media Player, so vids that play in WMP may not necessarily run in SharePoint.

So, it sounds like the codec in your vid is not supported by Silverlight. [MS have a list of what's supported, you should check if the codec is on the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28VS.95%29.aspx). If not, you'll need to use a different codec.